# Android Asynctask check status(finished)

Tags: android, multithreading, arraylist, android-asynctask

I am working on an AsyncTask class. I  try to parse Json  and show it. Everything is ok at the monment, but i have one  problem. I want to check the status of my Asynctask class. I mean i want to check when the AsyncTask is finished.

This is my code :

```
private class LoadItemFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {


                JsonResult = FlashScreen
                        .execute(
                                "***************",
                                FlashScreen.CreateJson(
                                        "GetCategoryHierharchy", "eng"));




        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            pDialog = null;
        }

        Log.e("serverrrr", JsonResult);
        try {
            ParseJsonFromServer(JsonResult);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}



public void ParseJsonFromServer(String server) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(server);
    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");

        Azercell_PagerTitleStrip_items objItem = new Azercell_PagerTitleStrip_items();

        objItem.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
        Log.e("titlesss", data.getString("title"));
        arrayOfList.add(objItem);
    }

}
```

My problem is on this part :

```
loaditem = new LoadItemFromServer();

    loaditem.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
     try {
         if (loaditem.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
             for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) {
                page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);
                // setAdapterToListview(page);
                titles.add(arrayOfList.get(i).getTitle());
                pages.add(page);
            }
         } else {
             Log.e("asynctask status", "not finished");
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
```

At the moment my `arrayOfList` array size is 0, but I  logged ParseJsonFromServer and this array's size is not 0.
I cannot wait, when does AsyncTask finish ?
How can I solve my problem ? If anyone knows a solution, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take this part of your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) {
    page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);
    // setAdapterToListview(page);
    titles.add(arrayOfList.get(i).getTitle());
    pages.add(page);
}
```

At the end of your `ParseJsonFromServer` method. (Also try to improve your coding below)

```
public void ParseJsonFromServer(String server) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(server);
    jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("result");

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("data");

        Azercell_PagerTitleStrip_items objItem = new Azercell_PagerTitleStrip_items();

        objItem.setTitle(data.getString("title"));
        Log.e("titlesss", data.getString("title"));
        arrayOfList.add(objItem);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfList.size(); i++) {
        page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.azercell_category_pages, null);
        // setAdapterToListview(page);
        titles.add(arrayOfList.get(i).getTitle());
        pages.add(page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when your onPostExecute() method is called it means your execution has been finished

Comment: yes i know it but  how i can write my for function inside onPostExecute()?i added view's in my for function

Comment: do your coding inside onPostExecute() if any problem Kindly show your full code

Comment: look @Cryzy , my for function must be call in onCreateView. i try to dynamically add view(this working) but my array's size is 0 .i can not wait while  asynctask is finished

Comment: you can simply move code for inflating your layout to onPostExecute() method of your AsyncTask

Comment: on onCreateView first call your asynck and when u have got the array then try to inflate your view on post execute